# Errors in functions.php after installing 5.16.2 on Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, installation

I'm running Drupal 7.67 on PHP 7.1 and am now getting the below error when I invoke Drush commands.

Another gripe is that upon install, Civi blew out my blocks settings, so I needed to reconstruct the site from a window I (thankfully) already had open.

I've not run into either of these issues before. Any suggestions greatly appreciated... thanks!

---

Warning: Unsupported declare 'strict_types' in /[site]/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/league/csv/src/functions.php on line 12

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '{' in /[site]/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/league/csv/src/functions.php on line 33
Drush command terminated abnormally due to an unrecoverable error.   [error]
Error: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '{' in
/[site]/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/league/csv/src/functions.php,
line 33

Answer (score 2):

You will need to upgrade php version to 7.x. also check your apache/nginx and cli are using 7.x version of php

See https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/requirements/#php-version

Comment: Agreed with Pradeep here - it sounds like you're using a different version of PHP on the command line.

Comment: Nope. I did mention that I'm running PHP 7.1 PHP Version 7.1.31, to be precise. 7.2 crashes the site for reasons I probably won't investigate until I have to.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE:
found the answer

long ago, someone had added alias drush='/usr/bin/php5 /usr/local/bin/drush' to /etc/bash.bashrc I commented that out and all works as expected

I hit this same issue recently.

debian OS, php 7.1 on command line and in apache; same modules enabled; same configuration; can't see any differences between phpinfo() via apache and php -i on command line.

in apache, no errors. When I try to run drush I get the error reported above.

My temp fix is that since I also have php 7.2 installed on the server is to force drush to run with 7.2 -- this works for now. 
for example: /usr/bin/php7.2 /usr/local/bin/drush cc all

I've been unable to find the source of the error.