# Civi 5.x not recognizing PHP 7.1 in Drush

Tags: php, drush

This is the second site I've noticed this on - in both cases, the site is running PHP   7.1.32, as reported on the Drupal system status page.

Error message:

CiviCRM requires PHP 7.0.0+. The web server is running PHP 5.6.40. Drush command terminated abnormally due to an unrecoverable error.

The Drush commands seem to execute, though. The commands have nothing to do with Civi, BTW - these are standard install/enable Drush commands.

See related issue at:

[Errors in functions.php after installing 5.16.2 on Drupal 7](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/31747/errors-in-functions-php-after-installing-5-16-2-on-drupal-7/31846#31846)

Any guidance appreciated...

Answer (score 3):

That sounds like your command line version of php is different to the one being used by your webserver.

See eg https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/44967/the-php-version-is-not-correctly-detected

Comment: Beat me to it by about 30 seconds. Yes agree with Aidan. @Billyjames the answers also given in your other post are also likely correct. Type `php -v` on the command line to see what the command line is using vs what the web server is using.

Comment: Nope. Here's the result: PHP 7.1.32 (cli) (built: Sep  4 2019 15:29:27) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies. Thanks for the response, though!

Comment: Is there a variable called DRUSH_PHP defined in .bashrc or .bash_profile in your home folder?

Answer (score 1):

I hit this on a few servers and it was driving me insane. 
Demerit's comment pointed me to the answer. 
long ago, someone had added 
alias drush='/usr/bin/php5 /usr/local/bin/drush'
to /etc/bash.bashrc
I commented that out and all works as expected